# Tackling malformed requests

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

We have a Java Application running on Tomcat as the AppServer & Apache as the Webserver.

Currently, we are handling Malformed requests in the Application itself. However, I was wondering if it's better to handle it in Apache by writing some mod or using some existing mod.

What's standard practice for this?

Comment: Can you be more explicit what you mean by "malformed requests". There are too many ways for creating bad requests to have a single mechanism for dealing with them.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau my question isn't about how to deal with them, it's more about whether I should deal with them anywhere outside the application?

Comment: Some of them should (and will) be handled outside the application and some can only really be handled inside the application. Which is which depends on the kind of malformed request.

Comment: The question is too broad. There's not such thing as "industry standards". You will have to be more accurate on the details. What are the requirements? What are you trying to monitor ( a single app, the whole Java container, a network traffic, ...).  In which measure the actual implementation meet the requirements, etc.

Comment: btw, it's bad practice not to accept any response, or comment why they don't fit.

Answer (score 2):

The standard practice is *not* to attempt to change what would otherwise be considered a valid request through modding.

The whole point of using a web container is so that it can host your application in a uniform way without really requiring dependencies between your application and the actual hosting.  Otherwise you would necessarily require the use of Tomcat as a platform.  Of course there's nothing stopping you from doing so, though it is not ideal.

The common practice is to check yourself the parameters passed in the request, and, in the case in which it is not a valid request for whatever reason, an exception is thrown and you catch it at the Servlet level and respond with an appropriate http code.  In addition to this, you declare an web.xml error page for generic errors or for specific http codes for a relatively clean response for an invalid call.

Comment: ` Otherwise you would necessarily require the use of Tomcat as a platform` - I don't understand what that means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user93353 It means you're limiting yourself to a single server technology. What if you decided not to use tomcat but a different server which would not support the handling of invalid requests would have been doing until then? You would need to add the code into your application anyway. By having the logic in the app itself, you do not care whether you're using a Tomcat or a Wildfly.

Comment: well said @DavidPacker.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab requests in several places before they reach the endpoint (and your application). If you want a single class that will handle all incoming requests then define a [filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and handle it there, if you're looking into something more global, lets say for all your entire Tomcat applications, try writing a [Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Valve/Example_localhost).

Comment: My question is not about how to do it, but whether it makes sense to do it anywhere other than in the application.

Comment: yes, that's why you have these in the first place, to handle "risky" requests before they reach your app/server, abort them (if needed), and return a response. it's how we handle some of our security considerations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've an apache HTTPD in front, proxying some requests to a Tomcat. Right? It's not very clear from your description.

The "completely malformed requests" will already be handled by *httpd* and the "this request has a wrong path/argument" will be handled by your tomcat app. So far, so good.

...the question is: why would you want to change that?! By doing so, you'd have two places to maintain and keep in sync. The HTTPD mod/config/whatever *and* the Tomcat webapp itself. This doesn't sound like a good deal to me.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on what level you're looking to do something.

If you wish to route HTTP traffic to HTTPS traffic this should be done on the web server level (IIS, Apache, Nginx). Inspecting headers can also be done on this level, such as blocking specific user agents from accessing your application or ensuring that one of your custom headers is present.

I'd advice against inspecting most other cases on the web server level, for an example you should validate the content of URL parameters on the application level; such as checking that a value in within a specified range. This both to avoid splicing in unnecessary logic into the web server but also to create better error message handling. You might also want your application to do certain things on error, a classic is simply logging the error in question.

The only advice I can really give is to check things on the appropriate level, but there are quite a few too many cases and combinations to give a simple guideline for all requests which may be malformed.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is [...] about [...] whether it makes sense to do it anywhere other than in the application?
>   - [user93353](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350554/tackling-malformed-requests/350900#comment754975_350562)

I'm going to trust you not to take me to literally. Take a look at this:

[image: OSI Stack]

Now we're not talking about your packets here. We're talking about malformed requests. But the similarity here is that malformed is something defined differently at every layer in your stack.

If it's malformed in a way that no application could ever make use of it then I'm surprised Apache isn't already handling it. If they aren't maybe you should create a fix and offer it to everyone.

If something is malformed in a way that is particular to your one application it would make very little sense to handle it at the server level (Apache). If you're scattering the handling around in your application you have a different problem. You should create a single place for this to be handled and direct work through there. There's no reason that single place can't be in your app.

If it's malformed in a way that other apps you might run will need fixed and are sure that EVERY APP you EVER RUN under this server needs this exact fix with nothing particular to them then maybe you have a reason to make a weird custom fix to Apache.  If you can predict the future that well though why waste time writing software? Go play the stock market.

If you expect you might have some apps that need this fix and others that don't then connect the ones that need it through a proxy. If that's to far for you then just live with the duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

Something me and my team also were able to solve , without even realizing that this was a problem .

We had a reverse proxy server which filtered out requests and redirected it to the respective vms which ran some servers in which we had our app deployed . If the request is coming to the server which is last in the chain *which will process the request* , we knew that whatever routes were given the request had it in its url .

A url would have logically two parts path_to_the_resource and data , according to me the path to the resource should be *checked* / *filtered* by the *server* / *proxy* where the request lands *obviously* and the data part should be handled by the application which knows what kindof data it requires and hence can filter the desired requests from the undesired ones.

This approach would also distribute the load between the server filterer and the app , this approach would also be better in most cases as these are separate contexts and based on the context the filtering entity can have more rules to filter the well formed request from the malformed .